# MongoDB findOne() and updateOne() with embedded document

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Assume I got the following document with embedded documents in arrays:

```
{
    "name" : "test",
    "children" : [
        {
            "name" : "child1",
            "children" : [
                {
                    "name" : "sub1",
                    "children" : [
                        {"name" : "c1"},
                        {"name" : "c2"},
                        {"name" : "c3"},
                        {"name" : "c4"},
                        {"name" : "c5"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "child2",
            "children" : [
                {
                    "name" : "sub2",
                    "children" : [
                        {"name" : "c1"},
                        {"name" : "c2"},
                        {"name" : "c3"},
                        {"name" : "c4"}
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "sub3",
                    "children" : [
                        {"name" : "c1"},
                        {"name" : "c2"},
                        {"name" : "c3"},
                        {"name" : "c4"}
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "sub4",
                    "children" : [
                        {"name" : "c1"},
                        {"name" : "c2"},
                        {"name" : "c3"},
                        {"name" : "c4"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As we can see, `test` has two children: `child1` and `child2`, while a child has their own children like `sub1`, `sub2`, `sub3`, `sub4`, etc, and so on.
Currently, I have to update some of the children content, but I ran into the following two issues:

### The first issue is about `findOne()`, when I accidentally made a typo (name `child1` should be `child2`):

```
db.collection_name.findOne({
    'name': 'test',
    'children.name': 'child1',  // -> should be `child2`
    'children.children.name': 'sub2'
})
```

I can still get document 'test' correctly, but since I made a typo and `sub2` is actually under `child2`, not `child1`, then how can I still get this correct `findOne()` result?

### The second issue is about `updateOne()`, when I try to update `child1`'s array `children`, it works good (the code is also like the sample from the official document):

```
db.collection_name.updateOne({
    'name': 'test',
    'children.name': 'child1'  // locate child1
}, {
    '$set':{'children.$.children':[some other content]}
})
```

But when I also try to update `sub3`'s array (under `child2`), the same way failed with error `cannot use the part (children of children.children.1.children) to traverse the element`, and here is the code with issue:

```
db.collection_name.updateOne({
    'name': 'test',
    'children.name': 'child2',
    'children.children.name': 'sub3'  // locate sub3
}, {
    '$set':{'children.children.$.children':[some other content]}
})
```

I will be really appreaciate if someone can help with these two issues, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first issue, you can use `$elemMatch` to find the exact element.

```
db.collection_name.findOne({
   'name':'test',
   children:{
      $elemMatch:{
         'name':'child2',
         'children.name':'sub2'
      }
   }
})
```

I guess that mongo does not support multiple nested array update, but if you know the subarray position you can use this approach.

```
db.collection_name.updateOne({
  'name':'test',
   children:{
      $elemMatch:{
         'name':'child2',
         'children.name':'sub3'
      }
   }
}
, {
    $set: {"children.$.children.1.children" : 
                    [
                        {"name" : "c1"},
                        {"name" : "c2"},
                        {"name" : "c3"},
                        {"name" : "c4"}
                    ]
         }
}
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! your solution works like charm!

Answer (score 1):

First Issue: The query return results when querying array as the match is evaluated against all elements of array i.e first match `'children.name': 'child1'` matches first element and second `'children.children.name': 'sub2'` matches the second element.

Use [$elemMatch(query)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) to match both the conditions to the same array element.

```
db.collection_name.findOne({
    'name': 'test',
    'children':{$elemMatch:{'name': 'child2', 'children.name': 'sub2'}}
})
```

Compare both the above approaches [1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-an-array-with-compound-filter-conditions-on-the-array-elements) & [2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-for-an-array-element-that-meets-multiple-criteria)

Second issue: Mongodb 3.6 now supports multiple positional updates through [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#arrayfilters) expression.

The below query to replace all children of sub3 children.

```
db.collection_name.updateOne(
 {'name': 'test'}, 
 {'$set':{'children.$[first].children.$[second].children':[some data]}},
 {'arrayFilters': [{ 'first.name': 'child2', 'second.name': 'sub3'}]}
)
```

The below query to push new child in the childrens of sub3 children.

```
db.collection_name.updateOne(
 {'name': 'test'}, 
 {'$push':{'children.$[first].children.$[second].children':new child data}},
 {'arrayFilters': [{ 'first.name': 'child2', 'second.name': 'sub3'}]}
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! your solution works like charm! Since I got two answers with the almost same approach but I can only pick one as accept, therefore I picked one answered a little bit earlier than yours :(, sorry about that! but anyway, thanks again!